# Unit Conversion Program - How to get a variable from one method to another?

Tags: java

I'm sure that there are better/easier ways to write this code, but I am only a few weeks into learning to program and the purpose is to use if/else if/else statements. What I am trying to do is take a value and unit of measure and then convert it to another unit of measure.

The first method: `getSmallestUnit` is supposed to convert any input into the smallest unit either inches or millimeters.

The second method: `getNewUnitConversion` is supposed then take the new value and convert it into the correct unit.

I'm not sure how to get the variable in and mm into the `getNewUnitConversion`.

When I run the program it just prints out the value for the constant example converting from 1m to ft it prints `0.00328084ft`;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinearConversion 
{
    //==================MAIN================
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner newConversion = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a linear unit to convert from: ");
        String fromUnit = newConversion.next();

        System.out.print("Enter a linear unit to convert to: ");
        String toUnit = newConversion.next();

        System.out.print("Enter a value: ");
        double value = newConversion.nextDouble();

        UnitConversion timsConversion = new UnitConversion(fromUnit, toUnit, value);

        timsConversion.getSmallestUnit();

        double conversion = timsConversion.getNewUnitConversion();
        System.out.println(conversion);

    }
}


public class UnitConversion 
{

    private String input;
    private String output;
    private double value;

    private double in, ft, mi, mm, cm, m, km;
    private final double inch_feet = 12;
    private final double inch_miles = 63360;


    private final double inch_millimeters = 25.4;
    private final double inch_centimeters = 2.54;
    private final double inch_meters = 0.0254;
    private final double inch_kilometers = 0.0000254;

    private final double millimeters_inch = 0.0393701;
    private final double millimeters_feet = 0.00328084;
    private final double millimeters_miles = 0.000000622;

    private final double millimeter_centimeters = 10;
    private final double millimeter_meters = 1000;
    private final double millimeter_kilometers = 1000000;

    public UnitConversion(String in, String out, double val)
    {
        input = in;
        output = out;
        value = val;
    }

    //Convert units to convert from (input) to its smallest form either in or mm
    public double getSmallestUnit()
    {
        if (input.equals("mi"))
        {
            in = value * inch_miles; 
            input = "in";
        }

        else if (input.equals("ft"))
        {
            in = value * inch_feet;
            input = "in";
        }

        else
        {
            in = value;
            input = "in";
        }

        if (input.equals("km"))
        {
            mm = value * millimeter_kilometers;
            input = "mm";
        }

        else if (input.equals("m"))
        {
            mm = value * millimeter_meters;
            input = "mm";
        }

        else if (input.equals("cm"))
        {
            mm = value * millimeter_centimeters;
            input = "mm";
        }

        else
        {
            mm = value;
            input = "mm";
        }
        return 0;
    }

    //Convert in or mm to desired unit of measurement
     public double getNewUnitConversion()
    {
        //convert from english standard
        if (input.equals("in"))
        {
            if (output.equals("ft"))
            {
                ft = in * inch_feet;
                System.out.println(ft + "ft");
            }
            else if (output.equals("mi"))
            {
                mi = in * inch_miles;
                System.out.println(mi + "mi");
            }
            else if (output.equals("mm"))
            {
                mm = in * inch_millimeters;
                System.out.println(mm + "mm");
            }
            else if (output.equals("cm"))
            {
                cm = in * inch_centimeters;
                System.out.println(cm + "cm");
            }
            else if (output.equals("m"))
            {
                m = in * inch_meters;
                System.out.println(m + "m");
            }
            else if (output.equals("km"))
            {
                km = in * inch_kilometers;
                System.out.println(km + "km");
            }  
            else if (output.equals("in"))
            {
                System.out.println(in + "in");
            }  
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Must enter linear unit of measure in, ft, mi, mm, cm, m, or km");
            }
        }
        //convert from metric
        else
        {
            if (output.equals("cm"))
            {
                cm = mm * millimeter_centimeters;
                System.out.println(cm + "cm");
            }
            else if (output.equals("m"))
            {
                m = mm * millimeter_meters;
                System.out.println(m + "m");
            }
            else if (output.equals("km"))
            {
                km = mm * millimeter_kilometers;
                System.out.println(km + "km");
            }
            else if (output.equals("in"))
            {
                in = mm * millimeters_inch;
                System.out.println(in + "in");
            }
            else if (output.equals("ft"))
            {
                ft = mm * millimeters_feet;
                System.out.println(ft + "ft");
            }
            else if (output.equals("mi"))
            {
                mi = mm * millimeters_miles;
                System.out.println(mi + "mi");
            }
            else if (output.equals("mm"))
            {
                System.out.println(mm + "mm");
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Must enter linear unit of measure in, ft, mi, mm, cm, m, or km");
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: "convert any input into the smallest unit either inches or millimeters." Can you explain further what this means? Perhaps by giving an example of the input and output.

Comment: Also, you should probably return some meaningful value from each function, rather than simply returning 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes in the function `getSmallestUnit()`. Change the following:

```
else if (input.equals("in"))
{
    in = value;
    input = "in";
}
else if (input.equals("km"))
```

Your code in its current state is checking those first two `if` commands and then will forcibly set `in = value` and `input = "in"` and hence will not pass for the next two `if` commands. It reaches the final `else` and sets `mm = value` and `input = mm` since `input` is neither `km`, `m`, or `cm` at that point. So you are only ever getting `mm = value` and `input = "mm` which is then passed into `getNewUnitConversion`. If you want to return values from `getNewUnitConversion` you will have to add a `return` statement to each `if`. The following should cover it:

```
public double getNewUnitConversion()
{
    //convert from english standard
    if (input.equals("in"))
    {
        if (output.equals("ft"))
        {
            ft = in * inch_feet;
            System.out.println(ft + "ft");
            return ft;
        }
        else if (output.equals("mi"))
        {
            mi = in * inch_miles;
            System.out.println(mi + "mi");
            return mi;
        }
        else if (output.equals("mm"))
        {
            mm = in * inch_millimeters;
            System.out.println(mm + "mm");
            return mm;
        }
        else if (output.equals("cm"))
        {
            cm = in * inch_centimeters;
            System.out.println(cm + "cm");
            return cm;
        }
        else if (output.equals("m"))
        {
            m = in * inch_meters;
            System.out.println(m + "m");
            return m;
        }
        else if (output.equals("km"))
        {
            km = in * inch_kilometers;
            System.out.println(km + "km");
            return km;
        }  
        else if (output.equals("in"))
        {
            System.out.println(in + "in");
            return in;
        }  
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Must enter linear unit of measure in, ft, mi, mm, cm, m, or km");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //convert from metric
    else
    {
        if (output.equals("cm"))
        {
            cm = mm * millimeter_centimeters;
            System.out.println(cm + "cm");
            return cm;
        }
        else if (output.equals("m"))
        {
            m = mm * millimeter_meters;
            System.out.println(m + "m");
            return m;
        }
        else if (output.equals("km"))
        {
            km = mm * millimeter_kilometers;
            System.out.println(km + "km");
            return km;
        }
        else if (output.equals("in"))
        {
            in = mm * millimeters_inch;
            System.out.println(in + "in");
            return in;
        }
        else if (output.equals("ft"))
        {
            ft = mm * millimeters_feet;
            System.out.println(ft + "ft");
            return ft
        }
        else if (output.equals("mi"))
        {
            mi = mm * millimeters_miles;
            System.out.println(mi + "mi");
            return mi;
        }
        else if (output.equals("mm"))
        {
            System.out.println(mm + "mm");
            return mm;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Must enter linear unit of measure in, ft, mi, mm, cm, m, or km");
            return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That should help.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have been staring at this thing and trying so many different things for forever. I can't believe I missed such an obvious issue as a missing else if statement

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that although you specify metres, your code runs both the `else` blocks in `getSmallestUnit`.  So 1 metre becomes 1 inch, and then later becomes 1 millimetre; which is 0.00328 feet.

Your code will work if you change the first line that has `else` by itself to

```
else if (input.equals("in"))
```

and then change the `if` above the next block to `else if`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a problem in `getSmallestUnit()`. If your input is "mi" or "fi", the second if would still execute its "else" part :

```
    else
    {
        mm = value;
        input = "mm";
    }
```

So input would always be treated as "mm", no matter what the actual input was.

It would be more correct to have a single if statement :

```
public double getSmallestUnit()
{
    if (input.equals("mi"))
    {
        in = value * inch_miles; 
        input = "in";
    }

    else if (input.equals("ft"))
    {
        in = value * inch_feet;
        input = "in";
    }

    else if (input.equals("km"))
    {
        mm = value * millimeter_kilometers;
        input = "mm";
    }

    else if (input.equals("m"))
    {
        mm = value * millimeter_meters;
        input = "mm";
    }

    else if (input.equals("cm"))
    {
        mm = value * millimeter_centimeters;
        input = "mm";
    }

    else // here you can decide if your default value is "mm" or "in", but you can't have both as you tried before
    {
        mm = value;
        input = "mm";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Next, you should decide what you wish your methods to return. There's no point in returning 0 in `getSmallestUnit()`. That method should have a void return value (i.e. return nothing).

In addition, there's no point in having all these private members - `private double in, ft, mi, mm, cm, m, km;`. It's enouth to have just one double member. `getSmallestUnit()` can calculate that value. BTW, `getSmallestUnit()` can be called by the constructor. It doesn't have to be a public method at all.
`getNewUnitConversion()` can store its calculated value in a local method variable. It doesn't need to store it in an instance variable.

After all my suggestions, the code will look like this :

```
public class UnitConversion 
{

    private String input;
    private String output;

    private double smallValue;

    private final double inch_feet = 12;
    private final double inch_miles = 63360;


    private final double inch_millimeters = 25.4;
    private final double inch_centimeters = 2.54;
    private final double inch_meters = 0.0254;
    private final double inch_kilometers = 0.0000254;

    private final double millimeters_inch = 0.0393701;
    private final double millimeters_feet = 0.00328084;
    private final double millimeters_miles = 0.000000622;

    private final double millimeter_centimeters = 10;
    private final double millimeter_meters = 1000;
    private final double millimeter_kilometers = 1000000;

    public UnitConversion(String in, String out, double val)
    {
        input = in;
        output = out;
        getSmallestUnit(val);
    }

    //Convert units to convert from (input) to its smallest form either in or mm
    private void getSmallestUnit(double value)
    {
        if (input.equals("mi"))
        {
            smallValue = value * inch_miles; 
            input = "in";
        }

        else if (input.equals("ft"))
        {
            smallValue = value * inch_feet;
            input = "in";
        }

        else if (input.equals("km"))
        {
            smallValue = value * millimeter_kilometers;
            input = "mm";
        }

        else if (input.equals("m"))
        {
            smallValue = value * millimeter_meters;
            input = "mm";
        }

        else if (input.equals("cm"))
        {
            smallValue = value * millimeter_centimeters;
            input = "mm";
        }

        else
        {
            smallValue = value;
            input = "mm";
        }

    }

    //Convert in or mm to desired unit of measurement
     public double getNewUnitConversion()
    {
        double outputValue = 0.0;
        //convert from english standard
        if (input.equals("in"))
        {
            if (output.equals("ft"))
            {
                outputValue = smallValue * inch_feet;
            }
            else if (output.equals("mi"))
            {
                outputValue = smallValue * inch_miles;
                System.out.println(mi + "mi");
            }
            else if (output.equals("mm"))
            {
                outputValue = smallValue * inch_millimeters;
            }
            else if (output.equals("cm"))
            {
                outputValue = smallValue * inch_centimeters;
            }
            else if (output.equals("m"))
            {
                outputValue = smallValue * inch_meters;
            }
            else if (output.equals("km"))
            {
                outputValue = smallValue * inch_kilometers;
            }  
            else if (output.equals("in"))
            {
                outputValue  = smallValue;
            }  
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Must enter linear unit of measure in, ft, mi, mm, cm, m, or km");
            }
        }
        //convert from metric
        else
        {
            if (output.equals("cm"))
            {
                outputValue = mm * millimeter_centimeters;
            }
            else if (output.equals("m"))
            {
                outputValue  = mm * millimeter_meters;
            }
            else if (output.equals("km"))
            {
                outputValue = mm * millimeter_kilometers;
            }
            else if (output.equals("in"))
            {
                outputValue  = mm * millimeters_inch;
            }
            else if (output.equals("ft"))
            {
                outputValue = mm * millimeters_feet;
            }
            else if (output.equals("mi"))
            {
                outputValue = mm * millimeters_miles;
            }
            else if (output.equals("mm"))
            {
                outputValue = smallValue;
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Must enter linear unit of measure in, ft, mi, mm, cm, m, or km");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(output + outputValue);
        return outputValue;
    }
}
```

Of course there are many other things to improve. All the constants should be static. The `getNewUnitConversion` method could accept the output type as an argument instead of passing it in the constructor (so you could use the same instance to convert from one unit to any other unit by multiple calls to this method).

Answer (score 0):

Return specific value in first function and call it in second. Also you can add argument in second function in type of first function for example you need a double in second function from first function;
 Function1(double d)
{/*do something with double d */ return d;}
 》》 
function2 (double dd)
{ dd = Function1(double); /*do something*/}